# SQL Server backup file 15GB is empty when downclick trying to export single table from this sep4 a weekly backup

Tags: sql-server, export

SQL Server backup file 15GB  no Backupset selected to be restored?
is empty when downclick trying to export single table from see attached why is that
is it permissions?

[seeTheBackupScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OxEG.png)

Answer (score 0):

Exporting and restauraing are two different concepts.

- An export is a extract, partial or full of one or more table or view.
- A DATABASE backup is a file containg binaries data close to the
  physical storage of data and metadata.

It is not possible to extract a part of the database from a DATABASE backup nor a differential of log backup.

To do some export, you have to use the export wizard that you get in the contextual database menue...

Comment: Hi SQLPro   can  you explain the following msg when I select the SEP04.BAK FILE., No Backupset selected to be restored

Comment: Test this file with the RESTORE LABELONLY FROM DISK = '???\SEP04.BAK'